# Algorithm for extracting phrases from sentence

Tags: java, php, c, algorithm

I am stuck with implementing algorithm for extracting phrases from sentence. Each phrase have to contain from 2 to 5 words. For example I have a sentence 'This text is about my wish to test it'. And I need to get an array with next phrases from this sentence:

1. This text
2. This text is
3. This text is about
4. This text is about my
5. text is
6. text is about
7. text is about my
8. text is about my wish
9. is about
10. is about my
11. is about my wish
12. is about my wish to
13. about my
14. about my wish
15. about my wish to
16. about my wish to test
17. my wish
18. my wish to
19. my wish to test
20. my wish to test it
21. wish to
22. wish to test
23. wish to test it
24. to test
25. to test it
26. test it

In PHP I start with code like this:

```
$text = 'This text is about my wish to test it';
$words = explode(' ', $text); 
// $words = ['This', 'text', 'is', 'about', 'my', 'wish', 'to', 'test', 'it']
```

Please help me to implement the main algorithm. It can by any other programming language (C, Java, Python), not only PHP.

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

SO is **not a free coding or tutorial service** You have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Comment: This can be done with a *sliding window*, where the window starts out as two words, going from the first, second, third etc. word. Then change the window size to three words, again starting from the first, second etc. word.

Comment: how about exploding on the "." and then depending on the window size show the needed amount of elements in the array?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thank you for the idea, problem solved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code of algorithm that I needed:

```
$text = 'This text is about my wish to test it';
$words = explode(' ', $text);
$wordsCount = count($words);

for ($i = 0; $i < $wordsCount; $i++) {
    $window = 2;
    $windowEnd = 5;
    if ($i + $windowEnd > $wordsCount) {
        $windowEnd = $wordsCount - $i;
    }
    if ($windowEnd < $window) {
        break;
    }
    while ($window <= $windowEnd) {
        for ($j = $i; $j < $i + $window; $j++) {
            echo $words[$j], "\n";
        }
        echo "\n";
        $window++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java

```
String text = "This text is about my wish to test it";

int indexFirst = 0;
while (indexFirst > -1 && text.length() > indexFirst +1) {
    int indexLast = text.indexOf(" ", indexFirst + 1);
    indexLast = text.indexOf(" ", indexLast + 1);
    while (indexLast > -1 && text.length() > indexLast + 1) {
        System.out.println(text.substring(indexFirst, indexLast));
        indexLast = text.indexOf(" ", indexLast + 1);
    }
    System.out.println(text.substring(indexFirst));
    indexFirst = text.indexOf(" ", indexFirst + 1);
}
```

returns

```
This text
This text is
This text is about
This text is about my
This text is about my wish
This text is about my wish to
This text is about my wish to test
This text is about my wish to test it
 text is
 text is about
 text is about my
 text is about my wish
 text is about my wish to
 text is about my wish to test
 text is about my wish to test it
 is about
 is about my
 is about my wish
 is about my wish to
 is about my wish to test
 is about my wish to test it
 about my
 about my wish
 about my wish to
 about my wish to test
 about my wish to test it
 my wish
 my wish to
 my wish to test
 my wish to test it
 wish to
 wish to test
 wish to test it
 to test
 to test it
 test it
```